# Opening PyQT4 QFileDialog in native mode without static helpers

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, webdav, qfiledialog

Is it possible to open QFileDialog in native mode without using the getOpenFilename static method?

*Background, in case someone has a different approach for me:*

PyQT4 QFileDialog provides the static method QFileDialog.getOpenFileName which is really handy and works well with one exception for me. I am attempting to access a large file on a sharepoint share it fails when I click open. This is because the WebDAV limit is breached when the file chooser attempts to open the file. I don't want the file chooser to open the file, I just want it to return the file name which I believe it will do if I set the mode to AnyFile.

For various reasons:

- I cannot increase WebDAV limits in registries.
- I could use a save dialog, but it will warn my of overwrite and this is just confusing too.
- The non native UI understandably does not support WebDAV API. (Or so it seems)
- Stubborn people refuse to break up their huge spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible: `QFileDialog` is the constructor for the built-in Qt file-dialog.

If using `getSaveFileName` avoids the access problems, you can try setting the [DontConfirmOverwrite](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) option to get rid of the warning message.